# Datatable return undefined offset but it return the data when I dd()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, datatables

I want to show data in datatable. it always return "undefined offset". but when I do "dd()" the data is exist. this is my code :

```php
->editColumn('role', function($data){
    // dd($data->user->roles[0]['name']); //when I dd the data is exist
    return $data->user->roles[0]["name"]; //always undefined offset here
})
```

Comment: Can you show us what the dd of the roles is? And what the dd of roles[0]['name'] is? This can greatly help in concluding what is going on.

Comment: @RobBiermann the dd() result is the name of the role which is "employee". and the dd user->roles is an one element of array.

Comment: please, do not tell me what is in it, show it ;)

Comment: Did you try to add it to varible and return that variable? Like: `$role_name = $data->user->roles[0]['name']; return $role_name;`

Comment: i did try to defined it into a variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
->editColumn('role',
    function($data){
        return $data->user->roles->map(function($roles) {
            return ucwords($roles->name);
        })->implode('[]');
    }
)
```

I did this and it works.